# Can I use arguments within the function definition?

Tags: syntax, sass

I wonder if the following syntax is correct for Sass:

```
@function foo($param)
{
    @return $param;
}
@mixin bar($paramOne, $paramTwo: foo($paramOne))
{
    test: $paramTwo;
}
#test { @include bar(foobar); }
```

With expected return:

```
#test { test: foobar; }
```

Doesn't seems to work (as [$paramOne looses it's value](https://github.com/richthegeek/phpsass/issues/139)) when using the following [PHPSASS compiler](https://github.com/richthegeek/phpsass) for SASS/SCSS.

This is the correct syntax? Or I'm missing something?

It's very similar how it's in [_vertical_rhythm.scss](https://github.com/richthegeek/phpsass/blob/master/Extensions/Compass/stylesheets/compass/typography/_vertical_rhythm.scss#L95):

```
@mixin adjust-font-size-to($to-size, $lines: lines-for-font-size($to-size), $from-size: $base-font-size) {
```

Comment: Why are you asking here, rather than keeping it within that issue thread?  There is nothing productive about posting it here.  If you want to know if it is "correct", then consult the Ruby version http://sassmeister.com/gist/78080cdec3a519c93f2a

Comment: @cimmanon I'm asking about the correct syntax of Sass stylesheet language as I'm not familiar with Sass. Should I post to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead? I think you answered already that it is correct and you can use arguments within the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that kind of syntax is completely valid as cimmanon posted it on [sassmeister gist](http://sassmeister.com/gist/78080cdec3a519c93f2a) (thanks) which is using Ruby version of parser. Some other parsers could have problem with that ([phpsass](https://github.com/richthegeek/phpsass) in that case) depending how they implemented that logic.

In case of issues, make sure that you're using the right parser for `scss` syntax, not `sass` syntax ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_(stylesheet_language)), e.g. [`new SassParser(['syntax' => 'scss'])`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225581/phpsass-returns-a-fatal-error)). See: [What's the difference between SCSS and Sass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass)

---

Note  that the same syntax was used in [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) (open-source CSS Authoring Framework) for Vertical Rhythm as:

```
@mixin adjust-font-size-to($to-size, $lines: lines-for-font-size($to-size), $from-size: $base-font-size)
```

but in the [recent version](https://github.com/Compass/compass/blob/stable/core/stylesheets/compass/typography/_vertical_rhythm.scss) it's just:

```
@mixin adjust-font-size-to($to-size, $lines: auto, $from-size: $base-font-size)
```